# Solve given qus without using partial fraction method

Tags: derivatives

$$z=f\left(x,y\right)=x^{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-y^{2}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$

Prove that $$\frac{\partial^{2}f\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x\,\partial y}=\frac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

Comment: Kindly use correct notation so we can understand your question. This is gibberish.

Comment: Check my edit..

Comment: What do you mean by partial fraction method? (This is normally a term one finds in integration problems). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The answer just hinges on performing the derivatives on one of the terms correctly, the other term is the same with the roles of $x$ and $y$ switched. You can also take the derivatives in either order. Start with the first term and see that the $y$ derivative is just:

$\frac{x^3}{y^2 + x^2}$

The answer is straight forward frome there.